# I have put up display none but while loading the page It is loading

Tags: css

[image]

You can see the image here
I have been loaded the page with the display none and the css style script is included from before the head tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct your code

> display: block;

the above one  is overriding your code

> display: none;

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `display: block;`

It is overriding your `display: none;`

Unless I am misunderstanding the question.